# Microsoft health bot service integration to Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, botframework

I have created a health bot on the microsoft health bot service, i want to connect the health bot to facebook messenger. The Health bot service documentation does not provide a clear way to integrate to facebook messenger since there is no option to generate the call back URL and Verify Token for facebook as seen from this documentation [Connect a bot to Facebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Is there a way that i could integrate my health bot to Facebook Messenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the Healthcare Bot Service encapsulates all of the app resources. Consequently, you are not able to access the Bot Registration and configure the bot's channels as you would normally. You are able to get the WebChat Secret in the Healthcare Bot Manager, which would allow you to embed the healthcare bot in a webpage. If this is something you're interested in pursuing, I'd recommend looking at the [Healthcare Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthBot-WebChat) on Github and this Stack Overflow [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890634/how-do-i-integrate-microsoft-health-bot-to-web-application).

Hope this helps!