# How do I integrate Microsoft health bot to web application

Tags: botframework

I have created few scenarios in health bot designer. I am trying to integrate with my front end. However, I don't see any complete documentation around integrate process. I have already referred https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthBot-WebChat without any luck. How do I get directline link for healthbot. I have tried with web bot and able to generate directline but not sure how to link web bot channel to health bot scenario. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can integrate the Healthcare bot service into a web application using WebChat. First, you need to get your WebChat Secret from the Healthcare Bot Service Manager. In the pane on the left, click on the integrations blade, select secrets in the drop down options, and copy the `webchat_secret`.

[image]

Once you have the secret, you can request a token from DirectLine and render a WebChat component on your web app. Take a look at the example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Healthcare bot</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }

      #webchat,
      #webchat > * {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>

    <script>

      (async function() {

        // Note, for the simplicity of this example, we are fetching the DirectLine token here;
        // however, it is recommended that you create a backend REST API to generate and manage 
        // your tokens.
        const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', 
        { 
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer <WEBCHAT_SECRET>`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: {
              // The user id must start with `dl` and should be unique for each user.
              User: { Id: 'dl_user_id' }
          }
        });
        const { token } = await res.json();

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

      })().catch(err => console.log(err));

    </script>
  </body>
```

Note, for the simplicity of this example, we are fetching the DirectLine token here; however, it is recommended that you create a backend REST API to generate and manage your tokens.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful and I am able to bring up the chat. However, I believe, the bot response are from inbuilt scenarios and not from scenario that I have developed. I have simple scenario that greet user with a message when user say anything. So now question is how do I trigger my scenario and not in built bot response? Is there a way I configure which scenario to invoke from front end?

Comment: There might be a round about way to trigger your dialog from the front end, but I will have to take a look at it. Otherwise, that would have to be configured in the management portal, but I don't believe they give you access to the conversation flow. You are, however, able to customize the welcome message to the user in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it. We need to add a model and enable the trigger through Health Bot Management Portal

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct way to trigger a scenario from the front end. If you want to completely rely on your own responses, then you have to turn off the built-in scenarios and call a scenario name in the event post javascript code.  Look at the "trigger" element below:
            botConnection
                .postActivity({
                    type: "event",
                    value: { 
                      **trigger: "your_scenario_name_here", args: {}** 
                    },
                    from: your_user_name,
                    name: "BeginDebugScenario"
                });